# How to avoid duplicate commits after my changes are merged into master branch in Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

We are using Gerrit in our project and we strive to maintain a linear history by always rebasing our local changes on top of any incoming new changes.

After I've committed my changes into my local master branch, I push them into the remote:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

This creates a Gerrit review for my commit. And when I run `git status` it says that my local branch is ahead of origin/master by one commit, because my new commit has not been merged into the the remote master branch yet. Keep in mind that there may be other commits for review by other developers which have not been merged into the remote master branch. This means that I cannot rebase my commit on top of them because they are not in the remote mater branch yet.

When my commit has been merged into the remote master branch, either before or after any other commits, and after I've run `git fetch origin`, running `git status` says that my local master branch and the remote have diverged, because the local version of my commit (its sha-1) is different from the remote version. Basically my commit is duplicated under a different sha-1. Then I have to run `git reset --hard HEAD~1` to delete the local version of my commit and then `git merge origin/master` to fast-forward my local branch to include the new changes from the remote master branch. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

A good way to avoid this is to use `rebase` instead of `merge`. To do this change your project settings in page `/admin/projects/YOUR_PROJECT` setting the value "Rebase if Necessary" for "Submit Type" entry.

After pushing the commit from Gerrit you can update your local repository using `git pull --rebase` or `git fetch origin ; git rebase origin/master`.

To go further, you can create a single local branch per commit, then pushing this branch to `refs/for/master` and rebase the same way as before. It has the advantage to not create dependency into differents commits.

Comment: If I rebase, my commit will still be duplicated.

Comment: It is because you merge it onto gerrit. If it is too late (you already merge it) you have to do what you mentioned in your question. My answer is to avoid this case for next commit.

Comment: What is the point of rebasing after I've pushed my commit to the remote?

Comment: Assuming your gerrit project configuration is set up to rebase instead of merging, the SHA-1 is not changed. Then the rebase process will apply new commit into your local master branch and skip your own commit you pushede before on gerrit. It will avoid to get duplicated commit.